# Assistance building Array structure to recreate JSON file

Tags: php, sql, arrays, json, pdo

OK, so i have the following JSON structure,

```
[
  {
    "User_ID": "2",
    "DESCRIPTION": "No Description Specified",
    "AGE": "20",
    "COUNTRY": "UK",
    "GENDER": "MALE",
    "ORIENTATION": "Straight",
    "PROFILE_IMG": "Thumb1403569297.jpg" 
  }
]
```

I'm returning this data from my database, building an array of results and then json encoding it.

```
"SELECT User_Posts.User_ID,
                   User_Account_Details.DESCRIPTION AS DESCRIPTION,
                   User_Account_Details.AGE AS AGE,
                   User_Account_Details.COUNTRY AS COUNTRY,
                   User_Account_Details.GENDER AS GENDER,
                   User_Account_Details.ORIENTATION AS ORIENTATION,
                   User_Account_Details.PROFILE_IMG AS PROFILE_IMG                
                        FROM User_Posts
                        INNER JOIN User_Account_Details ON User_Posts.User_ID = User_Account_Details.User_ID;
                       "
```

and

```
$users = array();
while ($row = $result->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC)) {
    $users[] = $row;
}

echo json_encode($users);
```

However, THIS:

```
[
  {
    "User_ID": "2",
    "DESCRIPTION": "No Description Specified",
    "AGE": "20",
    "COUNTRY": "UK",
    "GENDER": "MALE",
    "ORIENTATION": "Straight",
    "PROFILE_IMG": "Thumb1403569297.jpg",
    "NETWORKS": [
      {
        "TWITTER": "USERBOB"
      },
      {
        "KIK": "BLLOO"
      }
    ]
  }
]
```

Is the structure i'm looking to achieve, this will probably need to be a separate SQL query to gather the 'Networks', my problem is 'how' must i structure my loops and build the arrays such that this is the output?

Network query:

```
SELECT User_Posts.User_ID,
User_Social_Networks.NETWORK AS NETWORK,
User_Social_Networks.USERNAME AS USERNAME
FROM User_Posts
LEFT JOIN User_Social_Networks ON User_Posts.User_ID = User_Social_Networks.User_ID;
```

Networks sql structure

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `User_Social_Networks` (
  `ID` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `USER_ID` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `NETWORK` varchar(12) NOT NULL,
  `USERNAME` varchar(30) NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`ID`),
  UNIQUE KEY `User_id_network_id` (`USER_ID`,`NETWORK`),
  KEY `USER_ID` (`USER_ID`)
)
```

Comment: Where is your second query for the network information, you need to build the json in the loop the way you need it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This should give you the desire JSON

```
$users = array();
while ($row = $result->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC)) {
    $network = $result2->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC)
    $row['NETWORK'] = $network
    $users[] = $row;
}

echo json_encode($users);
```

Comment: Not quite there, but closer now